# NestJS: How to use async/awayt instead of RxJS in gRPC client code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, nestjs, grpc

I have a set of NestJS micro-services which are written using async/await in their APIs. After adding gRPC, I am able to use async/await in the server implementation of gRPC APIs, however the client code would always return RxJS `Observable`. Because of this, I have to wrap gRPC method calls into `firstValueFrom()`.

```
await firstValueFrom(this.orderService.getOrder({ orderId }));
```

I don't want to mix both paradigms, it is inconvenient, and it just adds redundant code. I went through [the Nest gRPC documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/grpc) and could find any references on how to use async/await instead of RxJS in the client code. At the same time, if they allow using async/await in the server APIs, I assume it is somehow possible to do the same on the client side.

**Q:** How to use async/awayt instead of RxJS in gRPC client code in NestJS?

Comment: Why do you want to use promises instead of RxJS? Nest's documentation makes it clear that it uses RxJS for RPC transports

Comment: @JayMcDoniel because we use async fictions all over the code. Also REST APIs that we have and that eventually call gRPC are declared as async.

Comment: Then call all your methods asynchronously on the RPC side and `return from(this.service.method(paramters))` to make it an Observable and use `async/await` everywhere else you need it

Comment: Have you tried to Promisify RxJS callback functions? You could do it with promisify in blue Promise, or in your own function, and call `resolve()` if error is null on callback, and `reject()` if there is an error. Don't know how RxJS works, but it's a callback and it can be promisified.